# не могу собрать проект в netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Везде пишут про файл manifest, но у меня он не создаётся и нигде вообще не упоминается, main класс выбрал, но jar файл так и не запускается пишет:

> no main manifest attribute, in .\Research-1.0.jar

в чём беда? куда ещё нужно вписать main класс?
у меня netbeans 11.1 jdk 12

Answer (score 0):

Манифест обычно создаётся всегда. В случае подобных ошибок нужно в файле манифеста указать главный класс:

```
Main-Class: com.example.MainClass
```

Подробнее можете почитать на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848642/how-to-setup-main-class-in-manifest-file-in-jar-produced-by-netbeans-project).

P.S. После перехода от Orcale к Apache, ИМХО, Netbeans стал сильно уступать другим IDE.
Лучше используйте Eclipse или Idea.